# How to separate comma separated values in SQL Server: An improvement to current query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which the data has been stored as comma separated as well as without comma separated in some rows.

I want to separated that values into the different rows. I want improvement/better way to do that as of my existing query if possible.

```
create table TestData (EmployeeCode Varchar(50), ServiceYear int)
insert into TestData values ('EMP001', 5), ('EMP002,EMP003', 10)

 SELECT 
    ServiceYear
    , Split.EmployeeCode.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS EmployeeCode  
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT ServiceYear
     , CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(EmployeeCode, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS EmployeeCode  
     FROM TestData
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY EmployeeCode.nodes ('/M') AS Split(EmployeeCode);
```

I am using `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2` as the database.

Why I store comma-separated values in the table is as below?

In my application, I show the message on ribbon for all those which birthday is today. Also, show the congratulation message for those who have completed five or ten years in the organization. So, the message is simply stored in a comma-separated in table for all those employees.

A sample message looks like

> Dear ABC, XYZ Happy Birthday from HR Team

I am trying to use the same procedure and table to send the mail to that users so I need to separate that comma-separated values into a row and join that employee table with the actual employee table to get their other details like name, employee code, email, reporting person and so on...

I want to use the same procedure and table for sending the mail to each individual employee.

Comment: Upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server and use `string_split()`.

Comment: You could also give `delimitedsplit8k` a go, but @GordonLinoff is right. Upgrading should really be on the cards here as 2008 is completely unsupported. Ideally, you should also be fixing your design so that you're not storing delimited data. Those are the *real* fixes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Noted - upgrade is in progress.

Comment: "stored as comma separated as well as **without** comma ..." Poor design decisions will generally cause problems for the lifetime of that decision. The primary problem is your schema. Fix that and the sql becomes both trivial and efficient.

Comment: @SMor It is because when a single value comes in select for a specific date then it stores without comma and when more than one value comes in select then it is stored as comma-separated value.

Comment: Right...the point is that you shouldn't store multiple values like that. If you need multiple values it should be multiple rows, not a delimited string. Delimited data like that violates 1NF.